# Remove html tag from Website - BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am crawling data from a website. This website has code like this:

```
<span class="demo-span">
    <b>Tag b:</b> 
    <a href="...">Hello</a> 
     world!
</span>
```

This is what I tried:

```
new_data = data.find("span",{"class":"demo-span"})
print(new_data.get_text())
```

Expected output:

```
Hello world!
```

But the actual output is:

```
Tag b: Hello world!
```

Comment: Somehow, I think this is easier to achieve if you render the HTML and access elements through their DOM hierarchy. Because you would like to keep hierarchy and visual arrangement of text material.

Comment: First, thanks for answer my question, did python have remove() like jquery. i want remove the <b> tag and get the text of the new <span>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**`decompose()`**](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#decompose) to delete a tag.

```
html = '''
<span class="demo-span">
    <b>Tag b:</b> 
    <a href="...">Hello</a> 
     world!
</span>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

new_data = soup.find("span", {"class": "demo-span"})
new_data.b.decompose()
print(new_data.get_text(' ', strip=True))
# Hello world!
```

Comment: First thanks for answer my question, i just try with "new_data.b.decompose()" but output return "None".

Comment: `deomcpose()` returns None and deletes the tag. Copy my code completely and print `print(new_data.get_text(' ', strip=True))`.